# VBA add new record to table in Access

Tags: excel, vba, append

I have a (linked) table [Traffic] with one field named [Log]
I have a variable IO which can be "I" or "O".

The only purpose of this function is to add a new record/row to table [Traffic] in column [Log] that is containing one string: a date stamp combined with an "I" or an "O" every time a form is loaded/unloaded.

I try to create a Function in Ms Access 2010 without success (Error: "Object Required").

Any help is highly appreciated.

```
Public Function AppendTxt(IO As String)
Dim sText As String
Dim sTableName As String
Dim col As Integer
Dim lLastRow As Long
Dim iHeader As Integer

sTableName = "Traffic"
sText = Format$(Now, "yyyy\-mm\-dd hhnn") & IO
col = 0

 With ActiveSheet.ListObjects(sTableName)
    'find the last row of the list
    lLastRow = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(sTableName).ListRows.Count
    'shift from an extra row if list has header
    If .Sort.Header = xlYes Then
        iHeader = 1
    Else
        iHeader = 0
    End If
End With
'add the data a row after the end of the list
ActiveSheet.Cells(lLastRow + 1 + iHeader, col).Value = sText

End Function
```

Comment: You have posted code of EXCEL, not ACCESS

Comment: At what point is this adding data to Access?? I fail to see that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Public Function Appendtxt(IO As String)
Dim sql As String
sql = "INSERT INTO tbl ( [timestamp], var ) " & _
"SELECT #" & Time() & "#, """ & IO & """ AS Expr2"

DoCmd.RunSQL sql

End Function
```

Assuming you were making a mistake when posting a piece of excel code here, this should do the trick.

**EDIT:** to get rid of any warning message, call the following function at the startup of the database.

```
Function fncSetOptions()
    Application.SetOption "Confirm Action Queries", False
    Application.SetOption "Confirm Document Deletions", False
    Application.SetOption "Confirm Record Changes", False
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip guys. This works. Do you have any idea to eliminate the popup message "You are about to append 1 row"?